# View Autosys job status as dependency diagram

Tags: automation, ca, autosys, workload

Are there any tools to display an Autosys (aka: CA Workload Automation) component as a diagram that shows the dependencies between jobs/boxes? I've heard of the Dependency Graph, but it doesn't appear to show the execution status of the jobs. Are there any other tools, CA or third party?

Thanks
Andrew

Comment: Have you resolved this one ever? I recently came across same issue. I ended up creating my own webserver that pulled the data out of Autosys and drew an interactive graph - I couldn't get iXp to do that for me. I wonder if there are any other solutions for this problem.

Comment: @Maciejg -- how did you create the interactive graph ? can you please share the details

Comment: Hi @Kamaraj! I created an interactive webpage with python and vis.js. I'll be happy to do that for you, if you like.

Comment: Thanks for your comments... I saw a open source code in GitHub which uses vis.js. https://github.com/atam84/autosys_viewer?files=1

Comment: @Maciejg did you share the your script somewhere ? Is it opensource ?

Comment: @Kamaraj no, it's not available anywhere, unfortunatelly. But if you'd share your autorep -J output somewhere, I'll try to create it for you.

Comment: we have more than 10k jobs and the list is very huge.. and i cannot share the jil files outside.

Comment: @Kamaraj the tool you've linked is awesome, thanks! Mine did similar thing - actually using the same vis.js library, but it was not that sophisticated. The one by atam84 is far better, imho. Are you facing any issues with that? Perhaps I could do some adjustments, if that could help. Or you can contact the author - let him know his work is useful and share your remarks. Anyway, thanks again for sharing your findings!

Comment: @Kamaraj I know its been a while but thanks so much for your html tool. It is extremely useful for our team!!

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at the iXp GUI for AutoSys?
I've used this and it's very good as it shows the dependencies in a list along with execution statuses and it also contains an overview diagram.